# export { default as Module } from './Module' not transpiling correctly for IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm using webpack and babel to build a web application. For some reason exporting an imported module with the syntax `export { default as Module } from './Module'` doesn't seem to transpile correctly for IE11 which causes the error

```
Const must be initialized
```

I was able to narrow it down to this particular piece of code because when I import the module directly (instead of importing it first into an intermediate module and exporting it) everything works fine.

Also I configured my `.babelrc` to transpile for IE 11

```
{"targets": {"node": "10", "ie": "11"}}
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9814

Comment: Flavio - please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It can be possible that dependencies were not being transpiled. Try to move your config to webpack.config.js as mentioned in the link suggested by @messerbill. If issue persist then please try to post any sample code that we can try to test with IE 11 browser to see the results. Thanks for your understanding.